# How do I get the day with leading 0's in SQL? (e.g. 1 => 01)

Tags: sql, sql-server

If today was the 1th of December, the above would print "1".
I want to print "01". How do I go about doing this?

```
Date = REPLACE(REPLACE(Substring([Date],1,10),'-',''), '/','')
```

Result: `2020/12/1`
Expected Result: `2020/12/01`

Anybody can give advice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is an application level function. You shouldn't be formatting for display in your database, let the database handle data, and your application handle display.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can convert to the correct format:

```
select convert(varchar(10), date, 121)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06d8aaf8d31bba0ad3fb4a49b19f8986) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank Gordon.it seems not work. i add the covert to my code REPLACE(REPLACE(SubString(convert(varchar(10), [date], 121 ),1,10),'-',''), '/' ,'') but it still result '2020/12/1',I am not sure if it is about EXCEL, because the days I took in EXCEL. EXCEL DATE is 2020/12/1.

Comment: @ericso . . . This does not say to add the `convert()` to your code.  This says to only use `convert()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **FORMAT**

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('01-DEC-2020' AS DATE),'yyyy/MM/dd')
```